# Word for the inward folding of biological organs

Tags: single-word-requests

The human brain increases its total volume by folding its surface area into peaks and troughs called gyres and sulci. The process whereby this happens is called *gyrification* (not sulcification, for some reason). The total surface area of the brain is about one or two pages of newspaper, much larger than the surface area of the skull.

The intestines curve back and forth within the abdomen and increase their total length to about 22 feet. This is not exactly inward folding, but the inside of the intestine has villi and microvilli that do look like an inward folding, increasing the surface area by several orders of magnitude, until it is about the total area of a tennis court!

I am looking for a word generally appropriate to this geometry, but applicable in a non-biological context. It should carry connotations of increasing complexity induced by inward folding. *Gyrified* is bad because nobody knows what it means, it only talks about brains, and could have been *sulcified*. I have been using *involuted*, but it’s not quite right because it involves rolling or curling in a spiral manner, coming from the architectural term *volute*, which is a spiral ornament on an Ionic column.

Comment: I think you want, somewhat ironically, *convoluted*. :)

Comment: @DanBron I thought that "to convolute" and "convolution" would be suitable answers to the question but the online dictionaries do not support me. For instance Lexico defines [convolute](https://www.lexico.com/definition/convolute) as a transitive verb but restricts its use to literature and language by saying "Make (an argument, story, etc.) complex and difficult to follow." There are other definitions of both words but "convolute" is only listed as an adjective with a specifically biological meaning and "convolution" is only listed as a noun describing the result of the  folding. Very odd.

Answer (score 2):

Another biological term is **invagination** which means involution to form a cavity.

Some other non-biological words might be **wrinkled** or **spiraled** which generally imply greater surface-to-volume ratios. An uneven surface may be **corrugated** or may have **furrows** in it.

Comment: I'm reminded of the word *tesseract*.